# How can i learn to create complex UI and graphics on my website?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, website-design, css

I have been scrolling through dribbble and i could see very impressive web design shots, so far i just create basic looking websites but i would like to improve on my UI with a bit of graphic design. How can i accomplish something that has a design that seems to have curves and not confined to a css box model like in the image below?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to draw those graphics? These look like vector graphics to me - so use a vector image editor to create an svg.

Comment: @BillyKerr I think OP is asking about how to create a web layout that is not visually in a grid-like structure.

Comment: @Luciano - to be honest, I'm not really sure what the OP is asking, which is why I asked for clarification, although you may be right.

Answer (score 2):

All web layouts *are* confined to the CSS box model. You just create the illusion that it isn't by using clever positioning tricks.

- In your example they actually used an SVG image (the green part) and a bit of CSS positioning. The SVG is a regular box shape, but it overlaps the content below it.
- You can combine that with other tricks for different effects, like border radius and/or slanted edges for example.

You have to learn how to work around the limitations of HTML + CSS to create the effects you want. Instead of browsing Dribbble (where you only see the designs) you should check out a web inspiration gallery like [Codepen](https://codepen.io/), where you can see the code behind the designs.